# Font and columns width are changed after installing Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-office-2016

After installing Microsoft Office 2016 the font is changed to "Calibri" from "Arial" and the columns width became smaller in all my old workbooks, and there is no problem if I open the same workbooks on other laptop that only have Microsoft Office 2010 installed.

- I have Microsoft Office 2010 and I didn't uninstall it before installing Microsoft Office 2016.
- both Microsoft Office are 32bit.

How to fix this problem and return the workbooks to their original state.

Comment: If you check your Windows Fonts control panel, is Arial still installed?

Comment: It's also possible the original documents were created with the Calibri font and your other laptops don't have that font, so they substitute Arial.

Comment: @HighTechGeek, both fonts are installed on both laptops and the original documents were created with `Arial` font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel:

Go to File, then select Options.

Select general and change "Use this as the default font:".

You may also need to go to Home, cell styles then right click on normal.  You should see an option to "Modify...".  This will change the "normal" font that Excel uses.

Comment: Thank YOU, it works and fix my old workbook, but it seems that I need to change the `Normal` cell styles for all old workbooks (one by one), so I record macro to run it on all old workbooks, Thanks again.

Comment: Your Welcome.  Changing the normal style will also work in Word.  Its under Home then Styles subsection.

Comment: Today I found that only unformatted cells are back to Arial but the cells that I changed its font color (when I design this workbook) its font remains Calibri, do you have any idea about this problem, maybe I do something wrong when apply the steps in your answer.

Comment: My only guess is some sort of Excel update reset the defaults, which might mean, repeating the above steps might help.

Comment: Thank You @Imager, I tried update office and fix/repair and didn't work. but when I change the font of all cells in all worksheets to "Arial" before applying the steps in your answer it works, now everything is fine, thank you for help.